# Create a file for each Google sheet row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to create a file, in a specific folder for each row in a Google sheet.
I would like the title of the files to be the content of the 1st cell of each row.

My script seems to be working except for the title. The files are named "untitled" and I can't figure out why.
Here is my code

```
function iterateThroughRows() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
 var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 data.forEach(function (row) {
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A:A").getValues();
  var folderId = "XXX"
  var resource = {
  title: values,
  mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
  parents: [{ id: folderId }]
}
var fileJson = Drive.Files.insert(resource)
var fileId = fileJson.id
 });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `row` to access the first element of array/or first cell, no need to use `SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("A:A").getValues();` as you already have the data.

Try following modification:-

```
function iterateThroughRows() {
 var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
 var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
 data.forEach(function (row) {
  var folderId = "XXX"
  var resource = {
  title: row[0], // First Cell/first element of array data
  mimeType: MimeType.GOOGLE_SHEETS,
  parents: [{ id: folderId }]
}
var fileJson = Drive.Files.insert(resource)
var fileId = fileJson.id
 });
}
```

Comment: Hello @vector do you have any idea of how to make this work in batch ? I am always reaching timeout limit after 50-80 rows. Thanks in advance